# How to control the back button navigation in iPad (UISplitViewController)ios xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, back, uisplitview

I have used the following code for deleting my login page from the navigationcontroller(viewcontrollers) so that it will not come into the view again when going back (back button).

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    if([[VCs objectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2] isKindOfClass:[loginViewController class]]&&(VCs.count>=4))
    {
        [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
        [VCs removeObjectAtIndex:[VCs count] - 2];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers: VCs];
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for iPhone. But for iPad, since we are using splitViewController, if we code like

```
NSMutableArray *VCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.splitViewController.viewControllers];
```

What we will be getting is  an array of navigationControllers. Is there a genuine logic by which we can delete a particular viewcontroller from the splitviewcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your split view controller, as you said, will return an array of nav controllers (depending on the project setup). Once you have a reference to those, you can manipulate them however you want.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *masterNavVC = (UINavigationController *)splitViewController.viewControllers.firstObject;
UINavigationController *detailNavVC = (UINavigationController *)splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;

//Now you have the master and detail navigation controllers, get your VC you need to manipulate
NSMutableArray *masterVCs = masterNavVC.viewControllers;
NSMutableArray *detailVCs = detailNavVC.viewControllers;

//Remove the ones you need to - this example is arbitrary. Put your logic here
if(masterVCs.count > 0 && [masterVCs[0] isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]])
{
     //Remove or add
}
```

Comment: But still i have an issue.The content of the mutablearray are one viewcontroller and another navigationcontroller it seens.Is it because of the segue?I used push sugue here and used performSegueWithIdentifieir method to call the segue.Is there anything in particular that we need to consider while using segue with splitViewControllers?pls help.

Comment: How to set them back?any idea?